# Christoffel symbols manipulation help

Tags: differential-geometry, proof-explanation, riemannian-geometry

We have $\sum_l\Gamma^{l}_{ij}g_{lk}=\frac{1}{2}(\frac{\partial(g_{jk})}{\partial{x}_i}$+$\frac{\partial(g_{ki})}{\partial{x_j}}$-$\frac{\partial(g_{ij})}{\partial{x}_k})$

Since $(g^{lk})$ is the inverse of $(g_{lk})$,

$\Gamma^{m}_{ij}=\frac{1}{2}\sum_k(\frac{\partial(g_{jk})}{\partial{x_i}}$+$\frac{\partial(g_{ki})}{\partial{x_j}}$-$\frac{\partial(g_{ij})}{\partial_{x_j}})g^{km}$

May someone please supply the linear algebra argument above ? the indices are slightly confusing me every time I attempt to understand the linear algebra argument.

Answer (score 2):

$\Gamma^{l}_{ij}g_{lk}g^{km}=\Gamma^{l}_{ij}\delta^m_{l}=\Gamma^{m}_{ij}$ (i'm using the summation convention)

Answer (score 0):

The Christoffel symbols are the *components of the connection* $\nabla$. They have a proper definition for any suitable connection, not just the Levi-Civita. $\Gamma_{ij}$ is a vector that describes how much the $i$th basis vector varies along the coordinate lines of the $j$th component. It is what we get out on the other side when we take the covariant derivative on our basis vectors:
$$\nabla_i \mathrm{e}_j=\Gamma^k_{ij}\mathrm{e}_k$$
In a more intuitive way, $\Gamma_{ij}$ is a vector that describes how much the $\mathrm{e}_i$ basis vector changes when we nudge it in the $x^j$ direction. ( [See this video](https://youtu.be/3NnZzRb7L58) ). We can use the equation above as well as the required properties of the connection to write expressions for the covariant derivatives of vectors, covectors, and eventually, tensors. I'll omit the details here, but it turns out that the components of the covariant derivative of a $(0,2)$ tensor are
$$\nabla_k T_{ij}=\partial_k T_{ij}-\Gamma^l_{ki}T_{lj}-\Gamma^l_{kj}T_{il}$$
The connection $\nabla$ is precisely the Levi-Civita connection if $\nabla g=0$ and if $\Gamma$ is symmetric in its lower two indices. This means
$$\nabla_k g_{ij}=\partial_kg_{ij}-\Gamma^l_{ki}g_{lj}-\Gamma^l_{kj}g_{il}=0\tag{1}$$
But equivalently,
$$\nabla_i g_{kj}=\partial_i g_{kj}-\Gamma^l_{ki}g_{lj}-\Gamma^l_{ji}g_{kl}=0\tag{2}$$
And,
$$\nabla_j g_{ik}=\partial_j g_{ik}-\Gamma^l_{ij}g_{lk}-\Gamma^l_{kj}g_{il}=0\tag{3}$$
A nice trick is that we can add $(1)+(2)-(3)$:
$$\partial_k g_{ij}+\partial_i g_{kj}-\partial_j g_{ik}\color{red}{-\Gamma^l_{ki}g_{lj}}\color{blue}{-\Gamma^l_{kj}g_{il}}\color{red}{-\Gamma^l_{ki}g_{lj}}\color{green}{-\Gamma^l_{ji}g_{kl}+\Gamma^l_{ij}g_{lk}}\color{blue}{+\Gamma^l_{kj}g_{il}}=0$$
But both $\Gamma$ and $g$ are  symmetric, so the blue and green terms vanish. In all,
$$\partial_k g_{ij}+\partial_i g_{kj}-\partial_j g_{ik}=2\Gamma^l_{ik}g_{lj}$$
Divide both sides by $2$ and contract both sides with the inverse metric tensor:
$$\frac{1}{2}g^{pj}\left(\partial_k g_{ij}+\partial_i g_{kj}-\partial_j g_{ik}\right)=\Gamma^l_{ik}g_{lj}g^{pj}=\Gamma^p_{ik}$$
Renaming the indices into the order we typically see them,
$$\Gamma^k_{ij}=\frac{1}{2}g^{kl}\left(\partial_i g_{il}+\partial_j g_{lj}-\partial_l g_{ij}\right)$$